# handling LargeBinary data in sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Are there examples of inserting and reading LargeBinary data (sqlalchemy/postgres) in chunks? I do not want to hold the entire blob/data in memory while doing the insert and read.

Comment: Did you have an example in the end?

Comment: No, I did not find any.